# Birthday paradox with M shared birthdays

Tags: probability, statistics, birthday

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Probability of 3 people in a room of 30 having the same birthday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25876/probability-of-3-people-in-a-room-of-30-having-the-same-birthday)

The [birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_paradox) is a common problem about the probability that any 2 people from a random set of $N$ people share any common birthday. My question is a generalisation: What is the probability that $M$ people from a random set of $N$ people share any common birthday. The only difference is generalising 2 to $M$.

I'm particularly interested in the case where $M=5$ if that makes it significantly easier to solve for.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25876/probability-of-3-people-in-a-room-of-30-having-the-same-birthday/25878#25878

Comment: See also Section 1.2 on page 2 here: http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~tkemp/180A/180A.LectureNotes.pdf