# Expected maximum number of simultaneous celebrators

Tags: probability, statistics, birthday

Suppose there's a set of 500 individuals. What is the expected number of coinciding birthday celebrators? That's easy - it's $500/365$, under the assumption of uniform distribution.

But a birthday can't be fractioned between different dates so of practical reasons, some days will have more and others less celebrators. I wonder what's the expected number of simultaneous birth dates on the most common day (i.e. the one with most people having been born).

My impression is that there's something I'm missing and that it's not as easy as the formula in the first paragraph. The reasoning is that if there's only 5 individuals, the expected number of celebrators on the most common day is not $5/365$ but only $1/365$ because it's most probable that the birthdays are spread across the year.

So, the suggested solution would be removing the first $365$ people, regarding them as likely having one day each. Then, keeping the remaining $135$, hence arriving at $1 + 135/365$.

But I'm so confused and uncertain that I need outside input.

**edit based on comments**

There's certainly at least two simultaneous celebrators on the most common day. So the expected number is $2 + something$. That *something* consists of the likelihood for each of the remaining $500 - 2$ individuals.

If there's $2$ people in the group, the expected value is $1 + 1/365$. If there are $3$ people in the group, the expected value is $1 + 2 * 1 / 365$. Is that correct?

Then, if we'd have $365$ people, the formula suggested above would render $1 + 365 * 1 / 365$, which is $2$. It seems intuitively correct to me. Am I missing something?

Finally, the original group size was $500$. Hence, the answer would be $2 + 135 * 1 / 365$ or, if you want, $1 + 500 * 1 / 365$. Can anybody shoot it down somehow?

Comment: With any (non-zero) number of people, the number of simultaneous birthdays on the most common day is at least $1$; so the _expected_ value of this statistic is also at least $1$, and not $1/365$ as you claim. In fact it is a little more than $1$, because the probability  that two or more of the five have the same birthday is not zero.

Comment: @TonyK I just verified with the source of my question and admittedly, you're right. In the light of your remark, what's the appropriate approach, then? I've got a suggestion in 5 minutes. Please take a look at the edit.

Comment: Your intuition is _way_ out, i'm afraid. With 365 people, the chance is infinitesimal that they all have different birthdays, so the expected value will be _at least_ 2; in fact, significantly more than 2, given that it is very likely that we see three or more people with the same birthday. This question is hard, unfortunately.

Comment: Check the [Birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)

Comment: @TonyK You've lost me there, mate. With 365 people, the expected value should be around 2, as I see it. It's **very** probable that 2 people are born on the same date **but** it's quite likely that there are many such 2-days. In fact, I sense that there are so many that the likelihood of a 3-day stealing a person from the 2-days and 1-days is rather insignificant. But it's more of a hunch than calculation so I might be awfully wrong... Weirdly complicated question...

Comment: @Garmekain I've read it as well as I could. Didn't grasp the actual answer to my question, though. Would you be a sport and point it out a bit closer, please?

Comment: My intuition says that with 365 people, the expected value will be between 3 and 4. I will program up a simulation of this to see whether I'm right.

Comment: OK, I've done that: one million simulations. The average value of the max number of people sharing a birthday is... $4.967$. So even higher than I thought.

Comment: @TonyK Very interesting. I guess my estimation was way off and your hunch spot on. Any thoughts on how to do the calculation more mathematically strict? It can't be **that** super complicated... Can it?!

Comment: I think your intuition is off here, too: yes it can be super complicated.

Comment: @TonyK my code at http://math.stackexchange.com/a/485548/6460 but using `people <- 500` and reducing the number of cases seems to suggest a mean of about $5.86$

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25876/probability-of-3-people-in-a-room-of-30-having-the-same-birthday

Comment: @Henry: Yes, I get the same value as you with $500$ people: $5.86$.

Comment: @TonyK - sorry, I had not realised your $4.967$ was for $365$ people

Comment: @TonyK Can you (or anybody else for that matter) post an answer to be acepted? Numerical solution by brute force and high hopes isn't the most elegant one but given the total absence of a more sophisticated response, this one will do just fine. It'd probably look even better to give a few examples (365, 400, 500, 1000 individuals).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment asked for an answer:

The following R code allows a simulation

```
maxhits <- function(x){ max(table(x)) }
meanmax <- function(people, days=365, cases=10000){
  eg <- matrix(sample(days, people*cases, replace = TRUE), nrow=cases)
  maxfreq <- table(apply(eg, 1, maxhits) )
  sum(as.numeric(names(maxfreq)) * maxfreq / cases)
  }
```

such as

```
> set.seed(1)
> meanmax(365)
[1] 4.9799
> meanmax(400)
[1] 5.2131
> meanmax(500)
[1] 5.8776
> meanmax(1000)
[1] 8.7057
```

though with 10,000 simulated cases I would not trust these results past the first decimal place

*Added:* This chart show simulated means of the maximum for up to $1200$ people

[image]

and rather strangely I managed empirically to get something which looks like a reasonable approximation to the mean of the maximum rounded to integers on this range with something like `qpois(0.9984, lambda=(1:1200)/365)` as a quantile of the Poisson distribution, illustrated in red. I would expect there to be a continuous function which did even better, though the first $40$ or so values do not appear to be on the same smooth curve as the rest of them