# Birthday problem with an arbitrary "year" and number of overlapping birthdays

Tags: probability

First off, I'm not a mathematician, so if I'm going about this in the wrong way, please let me know.

**The problem**

I have ~4.1 million timestamps (with second accuracy) when people logged into a website.  They were collected over a period of ~50.5 million seconds.  Some of these records are erroneous (one says that 7044 people logged in at the same second).  Assuming an even distribution of logins, find *n* where the probability of *n* people logging in simultaneously < 50%

**Current approach**

This seems like the birthday problem could be adapted here.  Given a "year" of 50.5M days, and 4.1M people the chance that two people will *not* share a birthday is [negligible](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(50,500,000%20permutation%204,100,000%20%2F%2050,500,000%5E4,100,000)).

I found [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/485504) with a formula for triplets (three simultaneous birthdays), but is there a way to generalize it for *n* simultaneous birthdays? I'm guessing it's not as simple as changing the 3 in the equation to an *n*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you had $N$ possible birthdays and $M$ people (with birthdays chosen independently and uniformly).
The probability of $k$ people sharing a birthday seems difficult to calculate, but much easier is the expected number of (unordered) $k$-tuples sharing a birthday.
Namely, there are ${M \choose k}$ possible $k$-tuples, the probability that a
particular $k$-tuple share the same birthday is $N^{1-k}$, so the expected 
number is ${M \choose k} N^{1-k}$.  The expected number of $k$-tuples is 
an upper bound on the probability of existence of such a $k$-tuple.

If $M$ is very large, ${M \choose k} \approx M^k /k!$ so the expected number of $k$-tuples is approximately $M^k N^{1-k}/k!$.  Thus in your case with
$M = 4.1 \times 10^6$, $N = 5.05 \times 10^7$ and $k = 7044$, the expected 
number is ridiculously small, about $9.5 \times 10^{-31722}$.  Even with $k = 6$, the expected number is about $0.020$.
On the other hand, for $k = 5$ the expected number is about $1.484$.
So it seems likely that the maximum number of people sharing a birthday is $5$.

Comment: That's great, exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks so much!