# What is the probability that throwing $m$ balls at random in $n$ urns at least one urn contains $c$ elements?

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

Let us fix a number of urns $n$ and a fixed capacity $c$. I would like to know which is the probability that $m$ balls, thrown at random in $n$ urns, "overflow", in the sense that at least one urn has assigned $\geq c$ balls.

There are several results in the literature about the *maximum* number of balls in an urn (in particular, Raab and Steeger's 1999 paper), but the results are all asymptotic with high probability. I need a precise analytical result.

Comment: Can you compute the probability that the first urn has more than $c$ balls?  By linearity that gives you the expected number with more than $c$ balls, which is not the same as the probability that at least one has more than $c$ balls but is an indication if the probability is small.

Comment: People use asymptotic answers because the formulas get messy.  One way to work it out is from the answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2117261/21585

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Consider the equation $$x_1+x_2+...+x_n=m$$ where $x_i$ denotes the number of balls thrown in urn $i$. Now our question minds about cases where at least one $x_i$ is greater or equal to $c$. This is equivalent to find number of the answers of that equation where $x_1\ge c$ or the number of answers of the following equation$$(x_1-c)+x_2+...+x_n=m-c$$

Comment: This does not reflect the times one bin gets more than $c$ nor the times more than one bin gets $c$.

Comment: Of course it does since there is no constraint on the rest of the $x_i$'s

Comment: since $x_1-c=y_1\ge 0$ so it contains both cases

Comment: The cases where more than one bin is overflowed is overcounted in this method (at least if you were thinking of taking the probability of $x_1\geq c$ and multiply by $n$).

Comment: It's trivial that it does not work—just try $n=c=2$, $m=4$.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that some information can be gathered by reversing the viewpoint, even in the case of non-uniform urns. Assume urn $i$ has probability $p_i$ of getting a ball. Consider an infinite ball-throwing process, in which balls are iteratively thrown into the urns. If you fix any window of $m$ balls, the number of balls going into urn $i$ has Poisson distribution with mean $mp_i$, and you are going to observe the same distribution when you throw $m$ balls. There are nice tail bounds for the Poisson distribution, and if $c$ is large enough they go down quite quickly, so you get a bound for urn $i$. You do the same for all urns and then apply the union bound.