# how many persons need to be in one room , so AT LEAST 3 people have the same Birth MONTH?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, birthday

how many persons need to be in one room , so AT LEAST 3 people have the same Birth MONTH ?

Another Answer i suggest : (correct me if i'm wrong) there should be 15 People at least , because if there's more people than months per year , then using Pigeonhole Principle at least two people are born in the same month.

Comment: 25 of course.Try the contradiction method.

Comment: What have you tried?  Usually one approaches these problems by trying to think of the largest group without the desired property.

Comment: Maybe related:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25876/probability-of-3-people-in-a-room-of-30-having-the-same-birthday and https://www.pleacher.com/mp/mlessons/stat/bday2.html

Comment: Your reasoning is correct, and it is formalized in the [Pigeonhole Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).