# Birthday paradox problem in terms of months

Tags: probability, birthday

**Question -**

Consider the following-

1. It is equi-probable to have a birthday in any month of the year.
2. 6 random people are put into a room.

Q1. Find the probability that at least two people have a birthday in the same month.

Q2. Find the probability that three of the people have birthdays in one month, and the other three have birthdays in another month.

---

**My Approach -**

**A1. 77.71%**

P( all 6 people have different birthday months) = (12 * 11 * 10 * 9 * 8 * 7) / (12)^6 = 665280 / 2985984 = 385 / 1728

P( at least 2 people have the same birthday month) = 1 - P( all 6 people have different birthday months) = 1 - 385 / 1728 = 1343 / 1728 = 0.7771

**A2. 12.96%**

P( at least one triple birthday month)≈1 − exp(−C(6,3) / (12)^2 )= 0.1296

---

I am unsure about my answers and my approach, especially for Q2. Any and all help will be extremely helpful.

Solved with reference to this post - [Probability of 3 people in a room of 30 having the same birthday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25876)

Comment: Do you want an exact answer, or good upper/lower bounds?

Comment: The formula you used for the triple birthday is an approximation; a [much better approximation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=birthday+paradox%2C+6+people%2C+12+possible+birthdays) is $0.1141.$ But one triple birthday is not good enough; you need *two* triple birthdays, which is much less likely.

Comment: I don't exactly know how to tackle this Q2. Would appreciate any help in figuring out the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Q2,

You want to

- split the six people into a group of three to share a birthday-month, leaving another group of three to share another month,
- choose two of the twelve months to be those months, putting the first chosen group into the earlier of the months, and
- and then divide by the total number of equally likely cases, so something like $$\dfrac{{6 \choose 3}{12 \choose 2}}{12^6} \approx 0.000442$$

Comment: I think the final $\binom21$ is wrong here. When you count $\binom 63$ you already get two _distinguishable_ groups -- namely the 3 people you chose and the 3 you didn't -- so we can just decide to assign the 3 people we chose to the numerically smallest of the two chosen months, and get all the possibilities that way.

Comment: @Troposphere That is a fair point - edited - thank you